# Error when attempting to parameterize a command with $ variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I'm trying to execute a command using the following code snippet:

```
foreach($package in (Get-Childitem *.dtsx | select-object -expand Name))
{
    DTUTIL /COPY SQL;"\$package" /DESTSERVER "$global:SSISServer" /FILE "$package" /Q
}
```

However doing so results in the following error message:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '/' operator.
At C:\Projects\RiskOptix\Code\Deployment\BuildAll.ps1:267 char:39
+         DTUTIL /COPY SQL;"\$package" / <<<< DESTSERVER "$global:SSISServer" /FILE "$package" /Q
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

I also tried

```
& DTUTIL "/COPY SQL;'\" + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($package) + "' /DESTSERVER '$global:SSISServer' /FILE $package"
```

But now this gives me

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server SSIS Package Utilities
Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.

At least one of the DTS, SQL, or File options must be specified.
```

But at least the command ran but it seems like it didn't receive any of the parameters I sent it ...I'm guessing there's a fundamental concept of PowerShell I'm overlooking or failed to grasp here. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing variables as arguments to a command, you don't need to quote them.  That being said, it looks like you have a rogue semi-colon in your command.  Semi-colons are optional in PowerShell, but when present, is used as the command separator.  In this case, you'll need to quote the argument that has a semi-colon, or create a variable for that argument:

```
Get-Childitem *.dtsx | 
    Select-Object -expand Name |
    ForEach-Object { DTUTIL /COPY "SQL;\$package" /DESTSERVER $global:SSISServer /FILE $package /Q
```

I've never used `diutil`, so don't know the commands arguments or syntax.

Comment: This worked - I guess my problem was not understanding how parameters are passed to a command from PowerShell

Thanks, this was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

try `Invoke-Expression` like:

```
Invoke-Expression "DTUTIL /COPY SQL;`"\$package`" /DESTSERVER `"$global:SSISServer`" /FILE `"$package`" /Q"
```

the whole string is evaluated first and result is then passed to powershell like normal command

Comment: It's still giving me the error 
Invoke-Expression : You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side 
of the '/' operator.

Comment: try: echo "DTUTIL /COPY SQL;`"\$package`" /DESTSERVER `"$global:SSISServer`" /FILE `"$package`" /Q" and design the output to the way you would run in win batch

Comment: Actually that gave me the idea - I used 
echo "/COPY SQL;""\$package"" /DESTSERVER ""$global:SSISServer"" /FILE $package /Q" | DTUTIL
..and surprisingly it worked. 

What is the difference between using it like this way, vs &, vs Invoke-Method, vs multiple strings for each parameter
eg DTUTIL "/COPY SQL; '\$Package'" "/DESTSERVRER '$Server'" "/FILE $package" "/Q"